# Postman: How to specify a client certificate for a particular request

Tags: postman

I'm using Postman to send POST and GET requests and on sending the first request I'll get a list of imported certificates from which I could choose the one to use.

Is it possible to force Postman to let me select a certificate each time I'd send a request (or specify which request uses a different certificate, like in SoapUI, in case I'm running a collection)?

I'd like to send two identical requests where one is sent with certificate A and another one with certificate B and analyze the responses.

Right now I could do it with closing the client and re-opening it, but it seems a lot of hustle for ~100 requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use newman for your request. 
With newman you can re-run the same collection with different certificate parameters times.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#ssl-client-certificates